# Checking permission for list of path in c#

Tags: c#, path

I have a method which checks for the permission of the given path and its working fine as shown below..

```
public bool IsAvailable(string path)
        {
            bool hasPermissions = false;

            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, path);
                try
                {
                    permission.Demand();
                    hasPermissions = true;
                }
                catch(SecurityException e)
                {
                    hasPermissions = false;
                }
            }

            return hasPermissions;
        }
```

Now my question is that I want to check the permission for list of path I mean I would pass list of path in the argument of the method and it should return true or false if it has the permission for all the path given in the argument like shown below

```
public bool IsAvailable(List<string> pathList)
{
}
```

can anybody help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic of overloading:

```
public bool IsAvailable(List<string> pathList)
{
    return pathList.All(path => IsAvailable(path));
}
```

Since the two methods have different *signatures* (different parameters means different definitions), they can co-exist. This just calls your existing method from the new one for each `path` in the list `pathList`, checking that all of them have valid paths.

Comment: if I give 2 path in pathlist its going to check for only first path ur code is not going to check for the second path..why???

Comment: @Neel If your first path is invalid, that is enough for the method to fail it, and return `false`. If all your paths are valid, this should work (and return `true`).

Comment: its working sorry I have used .any as you have first wrote that and then you edited so it happened..thanx

Comment: Yeah, thats right - I wrote it the other way around first, and decided this was a lot clearer. Glad to be of help! :)